# Best orientation for docking

Tags: orbital-mechanics, docking

Is there a preferred orientation to approach (or leave) a space station for docking? Is it from below? above? by change in the inclination (port or starboard) from ahead or aft?  I know recently the Soyuz has been using a bi-elliptic transfer orbit to get there. That makes me thing from below. I have also read that they have on occasion changed the station attitude for a docking. The pictures show the docking as always being on the earth side. But I don't know if that's because it's the best angle to approach, or because the docking section is the most massive and therefore oriented to earth by tidal forces.

Comment: Surely the best direction to approach from is the side the docking port is on.

Comment: The two common approaches are v-bar (Velocity Vector) and R-bar (radius vector).  The wikipedia article on this is quite good, frankly too good for me to be bothered writing up an answer.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_rendezvous  Read the section on methods of approach.

Comment: If you are approaching too fast, then I suspect approaching from above is better than approaching from below, because you want to slow down first so you should be getting yourself into a higher orbit. :-) Opposite if you are approaching too slowly.

Comment: The V-Bar and R Bar approaches are good information. It appears that the predominant concern is to avoid collision. In both those approaches if the craft stops working it will drift away instead of into the station. The Z-Bar approach is the change of orbital inclination. It doesn't have a drift away by default component, and I assume that is why it is not used.

Comment: @aCVn what's in Canes Venatici? ;-)

Comment: @uhoh You'll have to go there and see for yourself. ;-)

Comment: @aCVn I did! But when I got there I didn't see a thing. It was as if I were adrift in some kind of giant void' a super-giant void even. Not sure what it's called, but it was super-big and super void-like.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about ISS procedures, specifically, but in general it'd be preferred to approach from the orbit normal or anti-normal (from above or below), assuming the station is not tumbling. This means the docking port would appear to rotate as you approach it, so you just need to set up a roll rate to match. If you approach from any other directions the docking port appears to rotate away from you, which means you need to translate as well as rotate to keep up. 
In practice, this rate is low (one revolution per orbit) and not a difficult problem to solve, but lacking any other factors (such as lines of sight/clearance, not sprayrng the solar phnels with your thruster exhausts, etc) then an approach along the orbit normal would be easiest.

Comment: Can you expound on this "This means the docking port would appear to rotate as you approach it, so you just need to set up a roll rate to match."  It sounds like you are talking about the R-bar (radius vector) but dealing with a "roll rate" is not something I'm familiar with in this case.

Comment: I can try :) the orbit normal is the axis which is not the v-bar or the r-bar. The v-bar is on front of the station, or prograde. Now, if the statien is not in a controlled rotation (ie its holding a fixed attitude relatrve to the stars), one quarter of the way around the orbit you'll be 90 degrees off to one side, and half way around the orbit you'll be behind the station....

Comment: from your point of view, the docking port wiln always be turning away from you, even when you peint directly at it and hold stationary, a few min later it'll have turned to face away.

Comment: This requires you to perform both translation and rotation to keep chasing it around the side. The same occurs on the r-bar approach. But if you approach it from above or below, ie, not in the orbi al plane at all, the station appears to slowly rotate on an axis perpendicular to the plane (ie, around the line between you and it). this means that for a docking port set in the middle, it appears to rotate like if you're looking down on a record player. So to dock, you just need to roll your ship on the same axis at the same rate, and presto, just fly forward and dock. No chasing to the sides.

Comment: You know that scene in 2001 with the big wheel space station and the craft begins to rotate with it and docks in the center, thats an approach perpendicular to the orbital plane.  now in real life, the ISS is controlled to rotate once for each orbit, so one side is always earth facing (for comms and observations). so this makes the v-bar approach more accessable. I guess the question needs to specify if the station target is rotating in a particular way or not

Comment: I guess I don't understand your terminology.  When you say from above or below isn't in the orbital plane, I'm totally lost (normally that's the r-bar).  Also I can assure you that a roll rate as it's normally defined  - about the longitudinal axis of the spacecraft - is not something that is anywhere far from zero in the real world when docking.  

I would say that if you want people like me who have actually worked around spacecraft rendezvous to get your answer, you need to rewrite it incorporating some of these comments and add a diagram or two. Some references would also be good.

Comment: R-bar and v-bar are the custom terms here, they do not feature in any description of orbital mechanics that I know of. R-bar is from the station to the center of the planet in the orbital plane, not out of the plane like you suggest. And v-bar is prograde in the orbital plane. There aren't many perpendicular axis left. I thought orbit normal would be a very familiar term to someone who has actually worked around spacecraft rendevous.. Maybe the purple line in kerbal space program is clearer to you? I thinke I've expounded enough now, perhaps a book on orbital mechanics would help you out.

Comment: I've just added a bounty. It invites an improvement of this answer (as well as other answers). I wonder if some of the material in your comments could be moved back into the answer itself, and perhaps a link or two added?

Comment: I often approach along the normal vector in KSP, for the issues of geometry described here - approaches along other vectors require roll and translation to keep up with changing orientations along the orbit. But if you position one space craft a short distance normal/antinormal of another ship, within a quarter orbit they will collide if given no other thruster input - as they are in mildly different planes. This may be a concern for manned spaceflight operations - it isn't a failsafe vector.

Comment: A very good point @saiboogu

Comment: You lucked out! I need to free-up one of my bounties ASAP, and the only one awardable is this one. :)

Comment: @Saiboogu The normal approach IS actually a failsafe one, depending where in the orbit it is performed. When the Shuttle first approached Mir, it executed this approach, so for one half of the orbit, it needed to use thrusters to reach the station... if the thrusters failed, it would slow the approach and then start to drift away again. (The opposite happens on the other half of the orbit of course, but i guess you buy some troubleshooting time doing it like this). As far as I know, the approach was later changed to v-bar. And this answer applies only for stations in a non-rotating setup.

Comment: Good info, thanks. I guess it's like trying to dock at high tide vs low tide - time it right for wider margins  and safety.